# Validação de regex com indicative (adonisJs)

Tags: node.js, adonisjs, indicative

Estou tentando validar um CPF com regex utilizando o indicative do adonis.

Eu tentei dessa forma:

```
const { validations } = use('indicative/validator')
const { validate } = use('Validator')

const rules = (values) => ({
   doc: 'string|required|max:11|min:11|regex:'+validations.regex([new RegExp(/([0-9]{2}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[\/]?[0-9]{4}[-]?[0-9]{2})|([0-9]{3}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[-]?[0-9]{2})/g)]),
})

const messages = {
 regex: field => `${field} don't have the correct format`
}
```

```
class StudentController {

  async store ({ request, response }) {

    const estudante = { ...request.all(), user_id: request.user_id }

    const validation = await validate(estudante, rules(rules), messages)

    if (validation.fails()) {

      return response.validateError(validation)

    }
}
```

Porém quando eu realizo uma requisição para a rota que possui essa função com o valor de doc:
39257443828

Eu recebo esse response error:

> doc don't have the correct format

Eu testei esse regex em alguns sites de regex e esse valor passa, porém no validator do indicative está indicando que não está no formato esperado pelo regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se alguém precisar, consegui utilizando as `rules` como `array` e utilizando o `rule()`:

```
const { validate, rule } = use('Validator')
doc: [rule("regex", /([0-9]{2}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[\/]?[0-9]{4}[-]?[0-9]{2})|([0-9]{3}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[-]?[0-9]{2})/g),
      rule("required"),
      rule("min", 11),
      rule("max", 11),
      rule("string")]
```